# How to use the stap -L option?

Tags: linux-kernel, ubuntu-11.10, systemtap

I am following the SystemTap tutorial and I am trying to do exercise 1 from section 2.3 - ["Tracing. Exercises"](http://sourceware.org/systemtap/tutorial/Tracing.html#SECTION00033000000000000000). The `-L` option seems to never work. I got this script:

```
probe kernel.function("*nit*"){}
```

I type in a terminal:

```
$ stap -L PROBE t.stp
```

and nothing happens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ stap -L 'kernel.function("blahblah")'
```

Systemtap is great, but poor documentation.

Answer (score 4):

From [`man stap`](https://sourceware.org/systemtap/man/stap.1.html) (with `systemtap*-1.7-2.fc15.x86_64` RPMs installed)

```
   stap [ OPTIONS ] -l PROBE [ ARGUMENTS ]
   stap [ OPTIONS ] -L PROBE [ ARGUMENTS ]

   -l PROBE
          Instead of running a probe script, just list all available probe
          points  matching  the given single probe point.  The pattern may
          include wildcards and aliases, but not comma-separated  multiple
          probe  points.  The process result code will indicate failure if
          there are no matches.

   -L PROBE
          Similar to "-l", but list probe points  and  script-level  local
          variables.
```

"probe points" refer to 'kernel.function("blahblah")', etc. There is no keyword "probe" before and no probe handler afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following examples.

To get a list of all Kernel functions.

$ stap -l 'kernel.function("*")' | sort

kernel.function("vfs_read@/build/linux-lts-xenial-Hu9lgy/linux-lts-xenial-4.4.0/fs/read_write.c:440")
[....]

To get a Kernel function & arguments (local variables)

$ stap -L 'kernel.function("*")' | grep vfs_read

kernel.function("vfs_read@/build/linux-lts-xenial-Hu9lgy/linux-lts-xenial-4.4.0/fs/read_write.c:440") $file:struct file* $buf:char* $count:size_t $pos:loff_t*

[....]

Answer (score 1):

```
stap -L kernel.function("*nit*") | sort
```

Comment: You need the apostrophe for this to work: `stap -L 'kernel.function("*nit*")' | sort`

Answer (score 0):

Just to add on to what more learned people than me have said:

```
stap -L 'module("module-name-here").function("*")'
```

For regular kernel probes:

```
stap -L 'kernel.function("*")'
```

Hope this helps someone else in the future!